# Database auth failure in Dockerized Rails/Postgres app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose to run a Rails/Postgres app, but am having trouble creating the database without setting `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD="trust"`. The following docker-compose.yml appears to work just fine with "trust":

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec rails server -b '0.0.0.0' -p 3000
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules/
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

To make this work without "trust" I understand that I must define the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` when the Postgres image is initialized to set the default user's password. As such, we use the following .env file, already referenced by docker-compose:

```
POSTGRES_URL=db
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foobar
```

and alter config/database.yml to use the following default connection configuration:

```
...

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_URL'] %>
  # If POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set in the environment then use the default user
  # and that password to connect. If none is set, then assume that the creds
  # are elsewhere (e.g. included in POSTGRES_URL on Heroku)
  <% if ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'].present? %>
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  <% end %>
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
...
```

I then do the following in console:

```
$ docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
...
$ docker-compose run web echo container started successfully
Starting rails-dockerized_db_1 ... done
container started successfully
$ docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:create
Starting rails-dockerized_db_1 ... done
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Couldn't create 'rails_dockerized_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
...
```

As far as I can tell this configuration should be correct, however I am obviously overlooking something. Why am I seeing this auth failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `docker-compose run ...` never runs a handful of *very important* setup scripts used by the Postgres docker image. If instead of the commands above we...

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up db
... (wait for "database system is ready to accept connections")
$ docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:setup
```

then everything works as expected